# Why i am getting infinite loop

Tags: singly-linked-list, insertion

```
public void insertion(int data)
    {
        Node new_node = new Node(data);
        if(head==null)
        {
            head=new_node;
        }
        new_node.next=head;
        head=new_node;
    }
```

I want to insert the new_node when head is null.

I am getting infinite loop of first value which i want to insert in the node

Comment: Please tag the language. I'm assuming Java?

Answer (score 0):

When `head == null` is true, you essentially do:

```
head = new_node;
new_node.next = head;
```

Think about those lines carefully. After the first line runs, `head` *is* `new_node`. With that in mind, the second line is essentially equivalent to

```
new_node.next = new_node;
```

Which should highlight the problem. You're setting the new node's tail to itself! That will lead to a cyclic list that will continue infinitely when iterated.

You only want to set `head's`next`when`head`*wasn't*`null` initially:

```
public void insertion(int data)
{
    Node new_node = new Node(data);
    if(head==null)
    {
        head=new_node;

    } else {
        new_node.next=head;  // Only execute these lines if head already existed
        head=new_node;
    }

}
```